# Building a profile page (Editable) with different components in vue.js

Tags: node.js, vue.js, nosql, vue-cli

I am making a website with vue.js and I am trying to build Editable profile page with different components that editable.

So I have 4 components(avatar.vue, interest.vue,languages.vue,about.me).

I was thinking to build one page with all these components in it but, then I thought about redirecting(routing) the user to the specific component. But how do I store those changes? So, I can call the backend and then update or insert the data in the database using Node.js.

Please do not hesitate to ask any kind of questions.